# formik + yup and validating fields that are in a child react component

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

lets say i have the following code:

```
let addressSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstname: yup.string().required().max(35),
  lastname: yup.string().required().max(35),
  company: yup.string().max(35),
  address1: yup.string().required().max(35),
  address2: yup.string().max(35),
  city: yup.string().required(),
  stateId: yup.string().required(),
  zipcode: yup.string().required().length(5),
  phone: yup.string().required().matches(phoneRegex, 'Phone number is not valid')
});

let checkoutFormSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  billAddressAttributes: addressSchema,
  shipAddressAttributes: addressSchema,
});

<Formik
    initialValues={this.buildInitialValues()}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
    }}
    validationSchema={checkoutFormSchema}
>
    {formikProps => (
        <FieldWrapper
            Label={<Label placement="left">Email address</Label>}
            Input={<Field type="email" name="email" component={Input} />}
        />
        <AddressFormFields prefix="billAddressAttributes" />
        <AddressFormFields prefix="shipAddressAttributes" />
        )}
</Formik>
```

where `<AddressForm/>` has a bunch of formik `<Field/>` components for the address, like how the email field is being made.

The email field works fine, triggering all events and properly showing the validation errors, but i cant get any of the formik `<Field/>` in the `<AddressForm/>` to trigger any events like touch, or show validation errors. I am guessing its because the formikProps isnt being passed down to the `<AddressForm/>`, but I can't figure out what to do. I've searched thoroughly through the documentation and stackoverflow but i couldn't find any examples of how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the <AddressFormFields /> component? - I'm guessing that component might need access to Formik-context.

Comment: Formik also detects fields by `name`, so your two <AddressFormFields /> might need `name="billAddressAttributes"`, `name="shipAddressAttributes"`.

Answer (score 1):

`AddressForm` should have the context as it's placed inside the `Formik` component. Perhaps, you've made some mistakes in manipulating fields' names and prefixes. Here is the working example of the nested form:

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-nested-fields-1nvkj